# Is there a way to resolve the flow error "Message mention text needs to be specified." when posting a message to a Teams Channel?

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to post a message in MS Teams using @ mention. So I'm using  email address for this purpose. Yet I receive the flow error as shown below.

[flow error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMjdh.png)

Comment: I am getting the same error but only for a sideloaded app/bot.